# How to configure <Location> Directive specific to a Location/Directory on Apache Server and not on Server Level?

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, centos7, httpd, httpd.conf

- I am new to Apache Server Configuration.
- I went through the Apache Documentation and tried to understand the Basics as well as the Directives.
- But still, I am not able to figure out a configuration that I require for my current scenario.
- The Version of my Apache Server is 2.4.6 running on Cent OS 7.5.

---

**My Current "httpd.conf" file. (Contains Only the important bits)**

```
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
Listen 80
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName 127.0.0.1

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Location />
    AuthType shibboleth
    ShibRequireSession On
    Require valid-user
</Location>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myweb.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mywebsitecontent/"
    ServerName myweb
</VirtualHost>
```

---

**Problem:**

- According to the above configuration, typing "http://myweb/" in the browser URL will invoke Shibboleth Authentication as configured in `<Location>` directive.
- But at the same time, if I host any other website in the `"/var/www/html/"` folder for example say `"demo"` website.
- Now if try to access the `demo` website with http://127.0.0.1/demo/index.html, it will also invoke Shibboleth Authentication because of `<Location />` configuration. And I don't want that.
- I want the `<Location>` to only work for `"/var/www/html/myweb/"`.

---

**What I Tried:**

- `<Location /myweb>` - Not Working
- Nesting `<Location>` in `<VirtualHost>` - Not Working

---

- I don't know what I am doing wrong.
- Any idea/suggestion/solution/right direction will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location

```
<Location> sections operate completely outside the filesystem. This
has several consequences. Most importantly, <Location> directives
should not be used to control access to filesystem locations. Since
several different URLs may map to the same filesystem location, such
access controls may by circumvented.
```

I think you want something closer to this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/myweb/">
    AuthType shibboleth
    ShibRequireSession On
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myweb.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mywebsitecontent/"
    ServerName myweb
</VirtualHost>
```

edit:
I think you want to add another specific VirtualHost for the demo site.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myweb.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/demo/"
    ServerName demo
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "/var/www/html/myweb/">
        AuthType shibboleth
        ShibRequireSession On
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@myweb.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/mywebsitecontent/"
    ServerName myweb
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that the default VirtualHost is the one at the top.  So if you're accessing the site with http://127.0.0.1/ (note that ServerName will be 127.0.0.1, not demo, not myweb) you'll get the first one.

Comment: The behavior is same even if I use <Directory>. The Shibboleth Authentication is getting applied to the Server Level and hence to all the Applications hosted.

Comment: I'd think that would be desired behavior, but if not, put the <Directory> stanza inside the <VirtualHost> stanza.

Comment: Putting the <Directory> inside the <VirtualHost> exhibits the same behavior when it was outside. The Authentication is still working for all the Applications. This configuration is killing me.

Answer (score 0):

`http://myweb/demo/` is a subfolder of `http://myweb/` so your `<Location />` covers that.

You need to put the `<Location />` bit inside the `VirtualHost` block with `ServerName myweb`. Being outside any `VirtualHost` means it takes effect for all of your Apache server.

Comment: "demo" is not inside "myweb". It is outside "myweb". And I also tried nesting <Location> in <VirtualHost>, but still not working.